# I currently have an Angular service that contains the functionality I need. How can I have the service interact with a component?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I would like to know how I can successfully have my service pass its data to the required component that is located in a different directory.

Component

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-view-modal',
  templateUrl: './add-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-view.component.css']
})
export class AddViewComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddViewComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: inject ViewManagerService via the constructor of your component

Comment: How would I achieve this? Do I need to specify the service as a provider in @Component definition

Comment: You've set the providedIn for the service at root level. So you don't have to pass the service in the providers array of component (unless you want a new instance of the service to be injected)

Comment: I think you should read the docs once more: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Angular's [automatic dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection):

```
import {ViewManagerService} from 'path/to/view-manager.service.ts';
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';


@Component({ selector: 'app-add-view-modal', templateUrl: './add-view.component.html', styleUrls: ['./add-view.component.css'] })

export class AddViewComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
   private viewManagerService: ViewManagerService,
   public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddViewComponent>,
   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.viewManagerService.doSomething();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add your service to the provider in app module.ts file

Then add the service in constructor like below code

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {serviceClassName} from '../service/serviceClassName';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-add-view-modal',
    templateUrl: './add-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-view.component.css']
    })

export class AddViewComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public serviceName: serviceClassName) {}

ngOnInit() {}
```

Use the needed functionality or variable declared in service like below

```
 this.serviceName.finctionName();
```